# How to invoke a secure service through ESB?

Tags: web-services, wso2-esb

How to invoke a secure service through WSO2 ESB proxy service?

I am trying to invoke a secure service through my proxy service? I am facing authentication problem. the stack trace is:-

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:308)
   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:41)at  org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
   at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
   at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
   at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
   at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
   at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:530)
   at org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp:276)
   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
   at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
   at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
   at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Provide more detail. How is the service secured? How do you pass credentials to it?

Comment: They are using the wsp wsa tags for security.I also wanna know how we can provide them security credentials

Comment: How to call a secured web service through wso2??????

Comment: Reading a bit about **WS-Security**, **WS-Addressing** and **WS-Policy** should help you.

Comment: Yes, I was spending time on those on last couple of days...Thanks

Comment: @Namphibian the service is secured using web services security policy, using symmetric binding assertions, X509 policy token. I want to access this service:-